# Meaning of Lie Bracket term in Riemann Curvature Tensor Formula

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

The formula defining the Riemann Curvature Tensor $R$ is:

$$R(u,v)w = \nabla_u\nabla_vw-\nabla_v\nabla_uw-\nabla_{[u,v]}w$$

The most common geometric explanation I see for this formula is "parallel transporting $w$ around a small parallelogram defined by $u$ and $v$, and seeing how much $w$ 'twists' around". However, if this is the case, I don't understand what the $\nabla_{[u,v]}w$ term in the formula represents.

When deriving this formula, most sources ([like this one on page 8](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2016/REUPapers/Wan.pdf)) assume that $u$ and $v$ are coordinate vector fields, and therefore take $[u,v]=0$, sending the third term in the above formula to zero during the derivation.

What's the geometric meaning of the third term with the lie bracket? Are there any derivations of the Riemann Tensor which include it?

I know when the Lie bracket is non-zero, flow curves don't form a perfect parallelogram, and the Lie bracket vector "closes the gap", in a sense. Is this relevant?

[image]

(I also see many sources saying the Riemann tensor is the "commutator" of the covariant derivative. However, this isn't strictly true if we include the 3rd term.)

Comment: The second covariant derivative is $\nabla^2_{u,v}=\nabla_u\nabla_v-\nabla_{\nabla_u v}$, not $\nabla_u\nabla_v$.  So the "commutator" $\nabla^2_{u,v}-\nabla^2_{v,u}$ gives the expression $R(u,v)$ using $\nabla$ is torsion-free.

Comment: @user10354138 Does this mean that the Riemann tensor has no meaning if the connection is not torsion free? Also, do you have any sources which derives the second covariant derivative from first principals? I have seen the formula before, but I've never understood where it comes from.

Comment: For any connexion $\nabla$, the definition $R(u,v)=\nabla^2_{u,v}-\nabla^2_{v,u}$ still works.  Also, the correction term $\nabla_{\nabla_u v}$ in the second covariant derivative comes from Leibniz rule for $\nabla$ when you impose tensoriality of $\nabla^2$ in $u,v$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks. Do you have a source or reference text for learning more about this? I'm not used to thinking of the $\nabla$ operator without arguments. It's not clear to me how $\nabla^2$ is supposed to operate.

Comment: @eigenchris Saw this quite late, but fix some vector field $Z$ and consider $\nabla Z$, which is a tensor field (it takes a vector field $Y$ to $\nabla_Y Z$ and is tensorial since $\nabla$ is a connection) and can thus be differentiated, so we get a second covariant derivative $\nabla_X \nabla Z$ given by $$(\nabla_X \nabla Z)(Y) = \nabla_X(\nabla Z(Y)) - \nabla Z (\nabla_X Y) = \nabla_X (\nabla_Y Z) - \nabla_{\nabla_X \mathrel{\vcenter{Y}}}Z$$ Defining $\nabla^2_{x,y}Z := (\nabla_X \nabla Z)(Y)$ we thus get $$\nabla^2_{x,y} = \nabla_X \nabla_Y - \nabla_{\nabla_X \mathrel{\vcenter{Y}}}$$

Comment: @eigenchris. You can redo the proof in the link but this time calculate $w - DCLBAw$ where $L$ is the operator that lets you transport along the "gap" vector [u,v]. We need decompositions like $LB - 1 = (LB - B) + (B - 1)$. If we do everything carefully, there should be an extra term $\frac{BAw - LBAw}{rs}$ in the end which should be equal to exactly the (negative) Lie Bracket term ("gap" difference). This makes sense since we need to "pay" the extra price of having to move along the gap over the (now) pentagon instead of the rectangle.